# How to get unencoded Query Parameter in Node.js

Tags: node.js, query-string

I am doing Google Oath2 Implementation. For a particular `authorization_code`, I was constantly getting `invalid_grant`. I checked the value and found that the query string value was encoded.

Here is an example:

```
const parser = require('url');
url ='http://example.com/test?param=4%2F12'
const q = parser.parse(url, true).query
console.log(q)
```

My output here is

```
{ param: '4/12' }
```

I want my output to be

```
{ param: '4%2F12' }
```

as the correct auth code is a string with value `4%2F12`. How do I implement this?. There may be
many manual ways to do this. Anything that needs a minimalistic code effort would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @LaodeMuhammadAlFatih Thanks for your help! I guess this should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple. Just encode again the param using `encodeURIComponent`.

**Example:**

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent("4/12")) // Output: 4%2F12
```